# Conversion methods do not work in LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx, conversion methods should work, however, they are not working.

I have this code:

```
var funcionario = (from f in _db.Funcionario
                   where f.FunId == Convert.ToDecimal(funId)
                   select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

but a runtime error occurs concerning ToDecimal conversion.

> "LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'System.Decimal
>   ToDecimal(System.String)' del método, y este método no se puede
>   traducir en una expresión de almacén."

Any help will be appretiated. I am in .NET 4.5.

EDIT: For those who need translation of the error message:
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(System.String)' of the method, and this method cannot be translated into a warehouse expression"

Comment: Linq2SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Translating the error to English might be usefull

Comment: Translation using Google Translate: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal (System.String)' method, and this method can not be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: What value is `funId` ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I am using EntityFramework, however that expression is Linq2Sql, isn't it?

Comment: @jstuardo No there are 2 different things. Correct tags.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes OP had used unnecessary tags but it was clear that it wasn't Linq2SQL. So, I made it clear for you too :)

Comment: @I4V, Thanks:) And my first post was for the OP that would correct tags.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan happy now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `funId` before hand. The linq expressions in there are converted to SQL equvilants by EF at runtime. Not all functions are supported.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily `Convert` the value before calling LINQ query.

```
decimal funIdDec = Convert.ToDecimal(funId);
var funcionario = (from f in _db.Funcionario
                   where f.FunId == funIdDec
                   select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, if you'd need to convert values in your query, you can use [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) and [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) classes. They contain a set of method that have corresponding SQL functions and can be used to do things like that.

Comment: Thanks.. I have done so, but this is the simplest case. I have other case that I need to compare times of day. I have formatted the constant beforehand to be of HHMM format, but inside the LINQ2SQL expression, I have a DateTime column that I need to covert to HHMM format so that I can compare, but I have not found a function to do that.